# Calculate Aggregate Mode

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe :

```
ID CATEGORY AMOUNT
1   T1       1000
2   T2       1500
3   T3       2000
4   T4       3000
5   T1       2000
6   T2       2500
7   T3       7000
8   T4       4000
9   T1       1000
10   T2      1500
11   T3      2000
12   T4      3000
```

I want to `groupby` category and then get the mode of each category:

```
T1 1000
T2 1500
```

All the way to T4. When I run the below python code I get an error:

```
df['AMOUNT'].groupby(df['CATEGORY']).mode()
```

I get the below error

> AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'mode' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Answer (score 0):

You need to group full data frame and then apply `mode` function:

```
df.groupby(['CATEGORY'])['AMOUNT'].apply(lambda x: x.mode()[x.mode().index[-1]])
```

Comment: Your solution giving same error mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
df.groupby('CATEGORY')['AMOUNT'].agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mode` function from `statistics` module:

```
from statistics import mode
result = df.groupby('CATEGORY')['AMOUNT'].aggregate(lambda x : mode(x))
print(result)

#    CATEGORY
# T1    1000
# T2    1500
# T3    2000
# T4    3000
```